# Быстрое отображение данных из списка python

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс, который имеет 5 переменных; есть список с этими классами.
Мне нужно быстро отображать все данные из списка, типа:

a: abc

b: abc

c: 123

d: 123

e: 123

Я сделал через цикл for, но он очень медленный.
Эти переменные постоянно меняются, поэтому вопрос: как сделать быстрое и эффективное отображение этих данных, если в списке может быть 10+ таких классов?
Вот пример:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'abc'
        self.b = 'bca'
        self.c = 123
        self.d = 123
        self.e = 123

    #функция которая меняет значения постоянно
    #def move(x ,y, z, w, v):
    #    self.d += x
    #    self.e += y
    # и т.д...

car_list = []

for i in range(15):
    car_list.append(Car())

while True:
    for i in car_list:
        print("a: " + i.a + "\nb: " + i.b + "\nc: " + i.c + "\nd: " + i.d + "\ne: " + i.e)
```

Comment: А можно реальный пример привести, как используется печать данных об объекте, так что это является узким местом?  `while True:` не вызывает доверия как-то.

Comment: У вас явно "проблема XY". Вывод на печать - это всегда очень затратная по времени операция. Опишите более подробно вашу задачу помимо этого вывода на печать. Нужно ли вам на самом деле так часто печатать эти значения? Может быть вам делать это через какие-то промежутки времени, например. Или вообще вам на самом деле эта печать может не нужна на самом деле.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: 1. Накапливать данные в переменной и выводить одним принтом. 2. Использовать f-строки.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'abc'
        self.b = 'bca'
        self.c = 123
        self.d = 123
        self.e = 123

    def __str__(self):
        return f"a: {self.a}\nb: {self.b}\nc: {self.c}\nd: {self.d}\ne: {self.e}\n"

car_list = []

for i in range(15):
    car_list.append(Car())

while True:
    s = ""
    for i in car_list:
        s += str(i)
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом vars, например. имейте в виду, только, что этот метод будет выводить в виде словаря *все* переменные класса:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'abc'
        self.b = 'bca'
        self.c = 123
        self.d = 123
        self.e = 123

car_list = []

for i in range(5):
    car_list.append(Car())

for j in car_list:
    print(vars(j))
```

на выходе:

```
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'bca', 'c': 123, 'd': 123, 'e': 123}
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'bca', 'c': 123, 'd': 123, 'e': 123}
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'bca', 'c': 123, 'd': 123, 'e': 123}
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'bca', 'c': 123, 'd': 123, 'e': 123}
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'bca', 'c': 123, 'd': 123, 'e': 123}
​
```

Comment: проблема в том что цикл for забирает большую часть производительности программы, и пока выводится занчения то другие функции простаивают, есть ли способ выводить данные без цикла for? чтобы было быстрее?

Comment: вообще без вывода какой либо информации через print все работает очень быстро, но стоит мне добавить print в цикл и фпс падает на 70 процентов

Comment: стоит посмотреть в сторону async

Comment: print в принципе медленная функция. смотрите в сторону async, как вам выше советовали, и , возможно, sys.stdout.write вместо print